# How To Fix Seagate 250GB Loud Screeching Noise

Tags: noise, hard-drive

This hard drive has my Xbox files on it,in which i need,and i have already taken it apart and all in a clean environment,and it started by making a buzzing noise,and then when i got the head unstuck,it just started to make the loud screeching noise,and i really want those files back,and i don't have enough money to have someone recover the data.Thanks i am really stuck on what to do. And i have already tried to fix the head,by relieving the stress on it from the platter,but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You should never have taken it apart. Probably your only option now is data recovery using magnetic force microscopy. How much are your Xbox saves worth to you? If less than $30k approx, just forget it.

Comment: So um, why'd you take it apart in the first place? Now the only way to "fix" your drive is to put it in an ISO 5 cleanroom, assuming that the heads haven't already damaged the drive.

Comment: No matter how clean you think your environment is, if you have to ask this question it is **definitely** not clean enough.  A room clean enough to safely open a hard drive in costs more than your house to install and more than most people earn to maintain.  The drive is toast - doubly so since you've already opened it and messed around inside.

Comment: When I did Xbox support, I learned the three guys above this comment are absolutely right, as is Dave Tweed below.

Answer (score 12):

That loud screeching noise means that the heads are no longer riding on a cushion of air, but instead are touching the disk directly, physically wiping away your data. The drive is a total loss at this point.

Answer (score -1):

When your HDD makes loud noice usually it haves serious mechanical problems as bad sectors problems with the motor or another problems with mechanical parts.

better try to do a backup [Here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamefaqs.com%2Fxbox360%2F927749-xbox-360%2Fanswers%2F73319-how-do-you-back-up-your-hard-drive&ei=4ldjVajEMMy0ggSh24H4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEE18dMFvrFTmMm5Yrvpneg_zGeIw&sig2=VXGXLXEj5ZB37owxYGrLxA&bvm=bv.93990622,d.eXY) is a way to do a backup of Xbox.

> **Seriously do a backup NOW(If you have the chance).**

Comment: You can't do a backup if your hard drive isn't working in the first place.

Comment: @oldmud0 right, updated.

Comment: Too late - he took the lid off & let the magic smoke out.